# A Netrunner using a stealth program, apply the stealth effect only to his icon or also to all his programs active in the Netmap?

Tags: cyberpunk-2020, netrunner

When the netrunner is in a cell of the netmap, and run program "invisibility" for instance, do the other programs launched by netrunner will be invisible as well? Or only the Netrunner "icon" will be invisibile?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 5):

As stated on page 138:

> It overlays a false signal on your cyber-modem trace, making it
> appear to be harmless static. When activated, Invisibility will allow
> the Netrunner to pass unnoticed through the net.

This means it only applies to the netrunner.

Comment: Ok, but "Invisibility will allow the Netrunner to pass unnoticed through the net" would not make sense if the Netrunner is invisible but the icons of his programs are visible in the Netmap, cause in this case, the fortress can still notice the intrusion.